# Add images to Bitmap ArrayList with a method?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.uzayli_1));
images.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.uzayli_2));

mForeground = images.get(0);
mBackground = images.get(1);
```

I can add pics to ArrayList but I want to use the class also in other classes so I have to write a method for it.

```
public void addImages(ArrayList<Bitmap> images){
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        images.get(i);
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.));
    }
}
```

I want something like this but how can I define the drawable image after R.drawable. in a method?

Answer (score 0):

You already decoded it once, so use the one from the `ArrayList`:

```
Bitmap bmp = images.get(i);
mPages.add(bmp); //assuming that's legal
```

Or keep the resource id's in a list of `Integer`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
images.add(R.drawable.uzayli_1);
images.add(R.drawable.uzayli_2);
```

And decode later:

```
public void addImages(ArrayList<Integer> imageIds){
    for (int i = 0; i < imageIds.size(); i++) {
        Integer resourceId = imageIds.get(i);
        mPages.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceId));
    }
}
```

But you can't do both.